# Prove that uniform convergence of a series in a region $G$ implies uniform convergence in any portion of $G$

Tags: uniform-convergence

"Prove that uniform convergence of a series in a region $G$ implies uniform convergence in any portion of $G$." (Exercise 18.c PSet 15.5, Advanced Engineering Mathematics, 10th Ed.)

It's seems so obvious that I don't know what to write, but maybe I'm missing some subleties.

The definition of uniform convergence is the following

\begin{equation}
  \forall \epsilon>0 \exists N \forall n>N \forall z \in G |s(z)-s_n(z)|<\epsilon \tag{1}
\end{equation}

Being $G_1 \subset G$ a subregion, it's *clear* that it's also true that

\begin{equation}
  \forall \epsilon>0 \exists N \forall n>N \forall z \in G_1 |s(z)-s_n(z)|<\epsilon \tag{2}
\end{equation}

What should I write? The answer can't be "it's clear/obvious that".

By the way, "A region is a set consisting of a domain plus, perhaps, some or all of its boundary points." and "An open and connected set is called a domain" (kreyszig)

Thanks,
Luca

Comment: I think it's as obvious as you think it is. Maybe someone else here knows more than either of us.

Comment: I would agree with you and Ethan. Just write out the definition of uniform convergence, and since your variables that live in the portion of $G$ also live in $G$, the conclusion follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$G_1\subset G \implies $$

$$\sup_{z\in G_1}|s (z)-s_n (z)|\le \sup_{z\in G}|s (z)-s_n(z)|$$

for each $n $.

If the right side goes to zero, then the left one goes also to zero by squeeze theorem.

Comment: Thanks. I add that the definition of uniform convergence being used is $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists N \forall n>N \sup_{z \in G} |s(z)-s_n(z)|<\epsilon$.